# HttpWebException Operation has timed out

Tags: c#

I'm running into an issue where on the first request, and then randomly over time, my client is getting operation time out, with http time out set to 5 seconds. I have 3 other clients running on other machines that are not failing. This machine is windows xp and a bit slower, but it seems like this is happening too frequently. In these instances the server does not even receive a connection attempt. The below code is run in a loop with a monitor.wait so that it only polls every 10 seconds. I thought at first that I wasn't disposing of the connection properly but it seems like I am. I can't run a debugger on this machine(it's not my machine) so I'm struggling to find the issue. It seems like the client is sometimes too slow to even open a connection.

```
try
{
    Uri targetUri = new Uri(urlFormatted.ToString());
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Timeout = 10000;
    WriteInfo(this.GetType(), "Requesting URL: " + urlFormatted.ToString());
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    break;
}
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        logger.Error("Http request failed with errorcode:" + (int)response.StatusCode);
    }
    logger.Error("Error connecting to [" + server + "]", ex);
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        responseString = ex.InnerException.Message;
    }
    else
    {
        responseString = ex.ToString();
    }
}

if (response != null)
{
    try
    {
        //Response handling
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //errorhandling
    }
    finally
    {
        response.Close();
        response.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get more info? It seems like the exception is just saying "the operation has timed out", which doesn't give me a lot to go on. On my debugging machine I can get a connection refused message by shutting down my server, but nothing like this, where the server never receives the request.

Also note: The other machines are all windows 7, and a little beefier. They all have the same .net library installed.

More information:

> netstat -a 1 -n -p tcp

does not show the connection at all when it's attempting to connect but gets the operation timed out message. This seems weird. It's like it's not actually attempting the connection. It does show when it establishes correctly.

Comment: That sounds like a network problem, lost packets.

Comment: Well all of my clients are connected to the same patch panel on the same network so I would think it would happen to all of them if that were the case. It really feels like this client is just too slow to initiate the connection in time, but I don't know how to get the info to verify that.

Comment: No, when the timer starts it's count the ACK has already ben sent, andit's impossible to have a 5 seconds delay on the network without a problem. It can perfectly be a bad cord, if the ethernet cable has a problem this can happen. Try to ping some remote addresses like google in a continuous way and check if there are lost packets.

Comment: I ran a continuous ping and now the problem isn't occurring. I'm going to continue to monitor it, but the situations where it was happening most(startup/disconnect+reconnect Ethernet cable) don't seem to be causing it right now.

Comment: Ok so I got another client and started this again with the same problem happening. I have had a continuous ping going since then along with a netstat -p tcp -a 1

There haven't been any problems in the ping and I have yet to see my connection in the netstat when the connection is working

Comment: I meant to say when the connection is supposedly attempting but times out, I don't see it in the netstat. It should also be 
    netstat -p tcp -a 1 -n